# Computing most reliable path in undirected probabilistic graphs using Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, pathfinding

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161209/computing-most-reliable-path-in-undirected-probabilistic-graphs-using-java-fol).)

## Problem definition

We are given an undirected graph \$G = (V, E)\$ and a weight function \$w \colon 
 E \to (0, 1]\$. The weight of the edge \$e \in E\$, \$w(e)\$, describes its *reliability*, or, in other words, the probability that the edge is available. Given two distinguished nodes \$s, t \in V\$, we wish to compute a **most reliable** \$s,t\$ - path.

There is, however, a catch: the cost of a path \$(v_1, \dots, v_k)\$ is 
$$\prod_{i = 1}^{k-1} w(v_i, v_{i + 1})$$
and not 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k-1} w(v_i, v_{i + 1}).$$

There is however a trick to remember:
Prior to computing the path, set for each edge \$e\$ \$w(e) \leftarrow \log_d w(e)\$, where \$d \in (0, 1)\$. Then, compute the ordinary shortest path in the same graph using the modified weight function. Next, suppose \$P = (v_1, \dots, v_k)\$ is a shortest path in the graph. You return \$P\$ as is, and you return as its cost \$d^{c(P)}\$, where
$$
c(P) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k - 1} w(v_i, v_{i + 1})
$$
is the cost of \$P\$ in the modified graph.

## Solution

**MostReliablePathFinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public final class MostReliablePathFinder {

    Path
        findLeastReliablePath(
                UndirectedGraphNode source,
                UndirectedGraphNode target,
                UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        weightFunction = weightFunction.normalize();

        Queue<NodeHolder> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<UndirectedGraphNode> closed = new HashSet<>();
        Map<UndirectedGraphNode, UndirectedGraphNode> parents = new HashMap<>();
        Map<UndirectedGraphNode, Double> distance = new HashMap<>();

        open.add(new NodeHolder(source, 0.0));
        parents.put(source, null);
        distance.put(source, 0.0);

        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            UndirectedGraphNode currentNode = open.remove().getNode();

            if (currentNode.equals(target)) {
                return tracebackPath(target, 
                                     parents,
                                     weightFunction);
            }

            if (closed.contains(currentNode)) {
                continue;
            }

            closed.add(currentNode);

            for (UndirectedGraphNode childNode : 
                    currentNode.getNeighborNodes()) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Double tentativeCost = distance.get(currentNode) + 
                       weightFunction.get(currentNode, childNode);

                if (!distance.containsKey(childNode) 
                        || distance.get(childNode) > tentativeCost) {
                    open.add(new NodeHolder(childNode, tentativeCost));
                    parents.put(childNode, currentNode);
                    distance.put(childNode, tentativeCost);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no path");
    }   

    private static Path tracebackPath(
            UndirectedGraphNode target,
            Map<UndirectedGraphNode, UndirectedGraphNode> parents,
            UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        List<UndirectedGraphNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
        UndirectedGraphNode currentNode = target;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            nodeList.add(currentNode);
            currentNode = parents.get(currentNode);
        }

        Collections.<UndirectedGraphNode>reverse(nodeList);
        double pathCost = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size() - 1; ++i) {
            pathCost += weightFunction.get(nodeList.get(i), 
                                           nodeList.get(i + 1));
        }

        double base = 
                UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction.NORMALIZATION_BASE;

        return new Path(nodeList, Math.pow(base, pathCost));
    }

    private static final class NodeHolder implements Comparable<NodeHolder> {

        private final UndirectedGraphNode node;
        private final double cost;

        NodeHolder(UndirectedGraphNode node, double cost) {
            this.node = node;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        UndirectedGraphNode getNode() {
            return node;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(NodeHolder o) {
            return Double.compare(cost, o.cost);
        }
    }
}
```

**UndirectedGraphNode.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public final class UndirectedGraphNode {

    private final int id;
    private final Set<UndirectedGraphNode> neighbors = new HashSet<>();

    public UndirectedGraphNode(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addNeighbor(UndirectedGraphNode neighbor) {
        if (equals(neighbor)) {
            return;
        }

        neighbors.add(neighbor);
        neighbor.neighbors.add(this);
    }

    public Set<UndirectedGraphNode> getNeighborNodes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(neighbors);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !o.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        return id == ((UndirectedGraphNode) o).id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction {

    static final double NORMALIZATION_BASE = 0.5;
    private static final double NORMALIZATION_DIVISOR = 
            Math.log(NORMALIZATION_BASE);

    private final Map<UndirectedGraphNode, 
                      Map<UndirectedGraphNode, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(UndirectedGraphNode node1,
                    UndirectedGraphNode node2, 
                    Double probability) {
        checkIsValidProbability(probability);

        if (node1.equals(node2)) {
            return;
        }

        if (node1.getId() > node2.getId()) {
            UndirectedGraphNode tmp = node1;
            node1 = node2;
            node2 = tmp;
        }

        if (!map.containsKey(node1)) {
            map.put(node1, new HashMap<>());
        }

        map.get(node1).put(node2, probability);
    }

    public Double get(UndirectedGraphNode node1, UndirectedGraphNode node2) {
        if (node1.getId() > node2.getId()) {
            UndirectedGraphNode tmp = node1;
            node1 = node2;
            node2 = tmp;
        }

        return map.get(node1).get(node2);
    }

    UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction normalize() {
        UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction normalized =
                new UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction();

        for (Map.Entry<UndirectedGraphNode, 
                       Map<UndirectedGraphNode, Double>> entry : 
                map.entrySet()) {
            UndirectedGraphNode node = entry.getKey();
            Map<UndirectedGraphNode, Double> newMap = new HashMap<>();
            normalized.map.put(node, newMap);

            for (Map.Entry<UndirectedGraphNode, Double> neighbor :
                    entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                newMap.put(neighbor.getKey(), 
                           Math.log(neighbor.getValue()) / 
                                   NORMALIZATION_DIVISOR);
            }
        }

        return normalized;
    }

    private void checkIsValidProbability(Double probability) {
        if (probability.isInfinite()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("infinite probability");
        }

        if (probability.isNaN()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("NaN");
        }

        if (probability <= 0.0) {
            // Edge reliability of zero (0.0) should be represented by the 
            // absence of the edge.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too small probability: " + 
                    probability);
        }

        if (probability > 1.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too large probability: " +
                    probability);
        }
    }
}
```

**Path.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public final class Path {

    private final List<UndirectedGraphNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final double probability;

    public Path(List<UndirectedGraphNode> nodeList, double probability) {
        this.nodeList.addAll(nodeList);
        this.probability = probability;
    }

    public List<UndirectedGraphNode> getNodes() {
        return Collections.<UndirectedGraphNode>unmodifiableList(nodeList);
    }

    public double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = "";

        for (UndirectedGraphNode node : nodeList) {
            sb.append(separator);
            sb.append(node);
            separator = " -> ";
        }

        sb.append(" ").append(probability);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UndirectedGraphNode node1 = new UndirectedGraphNode(1);
        UndirectedGraphNode node2 = new UndirectedGraphNode(2);
        UndirectedGraphNode node3 = new UndirectedGraphNode(3);
        UndirectedGraphNode node4 = new UndirectedGraphNode(4);
        UndirectedGraphNode node5 = new UndirectedGraphNode(5);
        UndirectedGraphNode node6 = new UndirectedGraphNode(6);

        UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction wf = 
                new UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction();

        node1.addNeighbor(node2);
        node1.addNeighbor(node3);
        node1.addNeighbor(node4);

        node2.addNeighbor(node3);
        node2.addNeighbor(node4);

        node3.addNeighbor(node4);

        node5.addNeighbor(node2);
        node5.addNeighbor(node6);

        node6.addNeighbor(node2);


        wf.put(node1, node2, 0.1);
        wf.put(node1, node3, 0.9);
        wf.put(node1, node4, 0.9);
        wf.put(node2, node3, 0.9);
        wf.put(node2, node4, 0.2);
        wf.put(node3, node4, 0.1);
        wf.put(node2, node5, 0.2);
        wf.put(node5, node6, 0.8);
        wf.put(node6, node2, 0.99);

        System.out.println(new MostReliablePathFinder()
                .findLeastReliablePath(node4, node5, wf));
    }
}
```

## The demo graph

[image: Demo graph]

The demo output is

> ```
> [4] -> [1] -> [3] -> [2] -> [6] -> [5] 0.577368
> ```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: The code seems to suggest 2's neighbours are 3 and 4. The drawing suggests its neighbours are 1, 3 and 6. Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: @Michael There is `node5.addNeighbor(node2)` which handles the connection between nodes 5 and 2. Same goes for 2 and 6.

Comment: Didn't see the `neighbor.neighbors.add(this);` Gotcha.

Comment: Please use letters like A, B, C for your nodes instead of numbers. That distinguishes them more easily from the edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few things. Nothing to do with the algorithm.

```
UndirectedGraphProbabilisticWeightFunction
```

The fact that this is a class ending with the word `Function` is a sign this isn't a true class. The state that this encapsulates is the minimum probability and a list of connections between nodes. We already have that list of connections in the form of the node's `neighbours`.

I would change the sets of `neighbours` contained by the nodes to contain `Edge`s. An `Edge` would simply consist of a `Node` and a probability.

```
class Edge
{
   final double              probability;
   final UndirectedGraphNode neighbor;
}

class UndirectedGraphNode 
{
    private final Set<Edge> neighbors = new HashSet<>(); //maybe rename this

    public void addNeighbor(Edge edge) { //maybe rename this
        if (this.equals(edge.neighbor)) return;

        neighbors.add(edge);
        neighbor.neighbors.add(new Edge(edge.probability, this));
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the entire `WeightFunction` class. It also (I think) allows you to get rid of the ID concept in the `Node`.

Speaking of which, if you *cannot* get rid of the ID counter, consider generating the ID of the `Node` from a private static counter rather than forcing the user of the class to add one.

*(what happens if they add multiple `Node`s with the same ID?)*

---

On a related note, I question whether your `equals` function in a `Node` is good enough. I would say a `Node` is equal to another `Node` if their set of `Edge`s is equal.

---

`checkIsValidProbability` is a funny function. I would change it to

```
private boolean isValidProbability(Double probability) {
    return !probability.isInfinite() && !probability.isNaN() //...
}
```

If the user violates this, simply throw an exception saying "probability must be between zero (exclusive) and one (inclusive)". This covers all bases without being ambiguous.

---

`Path` should not be *told* what it's probability is. It should calculate it for itself. What if a user of the class wanted to create a `Path` where they didn't know the probability beforehand? What if a path is created and one of the Nodes within it subsequently gains or loses a neighbour? The probability of the path is then not reliable.

---

Sorry if that was a bit unstructured but hopefully there's something useful in there. I may add more thoughts as I think of them.

Comment: Looks like a follow-up question is already in order. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @coderodde No problem. If you ask a follow-up, drop me a comment here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I got the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NORMALIZATON_BASE = 0.5`, I would choose either \$d=\frac{1}{10}\$ or \$d=\frac{1}{e}\$. That would effectively map each edge weight \$w\$ to \$-\log_{10}w\$ or \$-\ln w\$, respectively.  (In other words, the instructions are slightly stupid, in my opinion.)

Comment: What instructions are stupid?

Comment: The fact that it asks you to pick a _d_ between 0 and 1 rather than telling you to just do -ln _w_.